# Formatting java text with void method

Tags: java

I have looked and cant find the information I am looking for. My code is functioning as I expect it to but I have one bit of code that I would like to improve.

The problem is that I can not call a void method within a print statement like this:

```
System.out.print("Water is a " + printTemp(temperature) + " at" + temperature + " degrees.";
```

printTemp(temperature is a void method so this won't work, as a result I found a work-around but it is not ideal:

```
System.out.print("\nWater is a "); 
printTemp(temperature);
System.out.print(" at");
System.out.printf(" %.0f", temperature);
System.out.print(" degrees.\n");
```

here is the full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class printTemp {

public static void main(String[]args) { 

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter the temperature: ");
Double temperature = input.nextDouble();
// takes the state of the water from the printTemp method and 
// the temperature to return a formatted output to the user 
System.out.print("\nWater is a "); 
printTemp(temperature);
System.out.print(" at");
System.out.printf(" %.0f", temperature);
System.out.print(" degrees.\n");

}

public static void printTemp(double temperature) { 
    String returnMessage = "null" ;

    if (temperature < 32 ) 
        returnMessage = "solid";
    else if (temperature > 212)
        returnMessage = "gas";
    else
        returnMessage = "liquid";
    System.out.printf(returnMessage);
}
```

}

This is for school thus there are conditions that must remain, printTemp MUST be a void method and the variable temp must remain a DOUBLE.

Comment: Nothing you can do with those constraints. Well, other than merging the 3 print statements into one: `printf(" at %.0f degrees.%n", temperature);`

Comment: I really dislike this kind of question : "How can I do X for my school assignment without using the recommended and cleanest way to do it ?"

Comment: I dislike posting on forums in general but I was not sure if there was a better way. Thanks for helping me learn!

Comment: SIdenote: This isn't a forum ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about to put the following code snippet

```
...
System.out.print("Water is a " + returnMessage + " at" + temperature + " degrees.");
```

to the `printTemp` method as the last line? Then in the `main` outputs nothing and you just write:

```
...
printTemp(input.nextDouble());
```

Comment: Thank you I tried to do this but the statement was in the main method thus java could not use 'returnMessage'.

Comment: only i had to do it like this so the double prints as an int:
...
System.out.print("Water is a " + returnMessage);
System.out.printf(" at %.0f degrees.%n", temperature);

Answer (score 0):

Use a class variable to hold the Temperature String word and use the void method to set it.

```
public class PrintTemp {

    private static String TempStr = "";

    public static void main(String[]args) { 
        [...]
        printTemp(temperature);
        System.out.print("Water is a " + TempStr + " at" + temperature + " degrees.");
    }

    public static void printTemp(double temperature) { 
        if (temperature < 32 ) 
            TempStr = "solid";
        else if (temperature > 212)
            TempStr = "gas";
        else
            TempStr = "liquid";
    }
}
```

Comment: The class is lowercase and the variable is uppercased... That's backwards

Comment: Do you really think that creating an instance field for solving that task is the best way?

Comment: This seems interesting but for the purposes of my assignment I would not be able to use this.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Is there a best way to solve this high complex task^^ Just wanted to add the other possiblilty that would work with OPs task description.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

```
public class PrintTemp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double temperature = 35;
        StringBuilder returnMessage = new StringBuilder();
        printTemp(temperature, returnMessage);
        System.out.print("Water is a " + returnMessage + " at " + temperature + " degrees.");
    }

    public static void printTemp(double temperature, StringBuilder returnMessage) {
        if (temperature < 32)
            returnMessage.append("solid");
        else if (temperature > 212)
            returnMessage.append("gas");
        else
            returnMessage.append("liquid");
    }
}
```

This is the easiest way to have printTemp modify the message without actually returning it and without using additional classes / beans.
But this does work only for objects (not primitive type) and amongst objects it does not work for Strings because in Java they are treated as a special case. (That is why I had to use a StringBuilder, StringBuffer would work too)

Comment: I think that it works great, but I believe it is a little above our current curricculum.

Comment: please post the solution when you get it

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay guys!

Here is the solution.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class printTemp {
public static void main(String[]args) { 
//Read in the temperature from the user
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("\nPlease enter the temperature: ");
//Call and insert the input into the printTemp method.
printTemp(input.nextDouble());
}
public static void printTemp(double temperature) { 
    //Decide whether the water is in a soild, liquid or gaseous sate. 
    String returnMessage = "null";
    if (temperature < 32 ) 
        returnMessage = "solid";
    else if (temperature > 212)
        returnMessage = "gas";
    else
        returnMessage = "liquid";
    //Print to the user.
    System.out.print("\nWater is a " + returnMessage);
    System.out.printf(" at %.0f degrees.%n\n", temperature);
}
```

}